# Fill array with datatable in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable

```
struct KlasStruct
{
    public string Naam;
    public int AantalUur;
}

KlasStruct[] Klas;

private void btnMaakLessenrooster_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string queryVakkenNaam = "SELECT Naam FROM Vakken";
    OleDbDataAdapter dAdapterVakkenNaam = new OleDbDataAdapter(queryVakkenNaam, 
        @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Project Officieel\Project_MagnusCurriculum\Project_MagnusCurriculum\Project.accdb");

    DataTable sourceVakkenNaam = new DataTable();
    dAdapterVakkenNaam.Fill(sourceVakkenNaam);

    for (int i = 0; i <= sourceVakkenNaam.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        // Exception happens here:
         Klas[i].Naam = sourceVakkenNaam[i]["Naam"];
    }

    MessageBox.Show(Klas[0].Naam);
}
```

The exception I get is:

> Error: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type
>   System.Data.DataColumn

Comment: the error is telling you exactly what's wrong.. are you not familiar with types in C#..? google the exact error message and you will see how many results it yields... show more effort please respectfully speaking, personally speaking I would use a `List<T>` of Class vs a Struct but there are better approaches to what you are trying to do as well...

Comment: We are not familiar with c#, we allready searched on google for quiete some time, no good results yet..

Comment: what do you mean `we are not familiar with C#` then perhaps you need to start here [C# Basics Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/) good luck

Comment: I just need help with filling an array with a datatable..

Comment: dod a google search I am sure you are capable of that..there are tons of examples of this.. if someone gives you the answer without you trying to show more effort on your end.. how would you be able to honestly support the code in the event of `Code changes and Request changes`

Comment: @Michieldepaepe, have you tried my suggestion mentioned below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array you are using `KlasStruct[] Klas;` is not initalize. you can use as below:

```
struct KlasStruct
{
 public string Naam;
 public int AantalUur;
}

List<KlasStruct> Klas =new List<KlasStruct>();

private void btnMaakLessenrooster_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //add a try catch
    string queryVakkenNaam = "SELECT Naam FROM Vakken";
    OleDbDataAdapter dAdapterVakkenNaam = new OleDbDataAdapter(queryVakkenNaam, 
        @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Project Officieel\Project_MagnusCurriculum\Project_MagnusCurriculum\Project.accdb");

    DataTable sourceVakkenNaam = new DataTable();
    dAdapterVakkenNaam.Fill(sourceVakkenNaam);

    for (int i = 0; i <= sourceVakkenNaam.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
         KlasStruct kStruct = new KlasStruct(); ;
         kStruct.Naam = Convert.ToString(sourceVakkenNaam.Rows[i]["Naam"]);

         Klas.Add(kStruct);
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this gives no errors when running the program, but when i click the button that runs the code this error occures: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Project_MagnusCurriculum.exe"

Comment: you can add a `try - catch` block and find.

Comment: I show the error in a messagebox and it shows me the name of my project

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the `Rows` property inside your loop:

```
foreach (int i = 0; i < sourceVakkenNaam.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    Klas[i].Naam = sourceVakkenNaam.Rows[i]["Naam"];
}
```